# spark-submit on local windows command line is failing | java.io.IOException: Failed to connect

Tags: spark-submit

I am trying to run the spark-submit from my local window box from command line, however, it is failing to connect. It was working couple of days back. I am not able to recall any changes I made to my box.

```
spark-submit --class com.saulearning.spark.PopularMovies PopularMovies.jar
```

> ```
> 19/08/27 15:40:22 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
> java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to {my machine name}/<local IP>:<Port>
>         at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
>         at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
>         at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:368)
>         at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply$mcV$sp(NettyRpcEnv.scala:336)
>         at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:335)
>         at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:335)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1415)
>         at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:339)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:665)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:489)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:755)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:747)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:747)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:312)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: WKWIN3407831.global.publicisgroupe.net/192.168.56.1:54018
>         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>         at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
>         at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
>         at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
>         at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>         at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>         at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>         at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
>         at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
>         ... 1 more
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
>         ... 11 more
> ```

Comment: You are either having a network issue or the service is stopped. All these netty errors are just telling that the connection can not be established at the network level.

Comment: Thanks Léa. I am not sure why this error was coming as I was running the command on my laptop. To my surprise, I tried it again today and it started working fine. I am still clue less on what was the issue and how it got fixed and if it come back, what should I do to resolve this. Is there any configuration or software I can check to avoid this situation to occur again?